# Is there any unsupervised learning algorithm that do not not assign k

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

A traditional unsupervised learning approaches normally needs to assign number of clustering (K) before computing, but what if I do not know the exact number of K and exclude the k out of algorithm, I mean, Is there any unsupervised learning algorithm that do not need assign any k, so we can get k clustering automatically?

Answer (score 0):

- Affinity propagation
- DBSCAN
- Mean shift

For more details, check scikit-learn docs [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to infer the amount of clusters by metrics such as [Akaike information criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion), [Bayes information criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion), using the [Silhouette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)) or the [Elbow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering)). I've also heard people talk about automatic clustering methods based on self-organizing maps ([SOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map)), but you'd have to do your own research there.

In my experience it usually just boils down to exploring the data with manifold methods such as [t-SNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding) and/or density based methods such as [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) and then setting k either manually or with a suitable heuristic.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) in graph's theory. You can achieve clustering either bottom up or top down.

**Bottom up**

- define distance metric (Euclidean, Manhattan...)
- start with each point in its own cluster
- merge closest two clusters

There are three ways to select closest cluster:

- complete link -> two clusters with the smallest maximum pairwise distance
- single link ->  two clusters with the smallest minimum pairwise distance
- average link -> average distance between all pairwise distances

Single linkage clustering can be solved with Kruskalov minimum spanning tree algorithm, however while easy to understand it runs in O(n^3). There is a variation of Prim's algorithm for MST which can solve this in O(nˇ2).

**Top-down aka Divisive Analysis**
Start with all points in the same cluster and divide clusters at each iteration.

[divisive analysis](http://www.dpye.iimas.unam.mx/lety/archivos/multivariado2018_1/clases/cluster/Divisive%20Analysis%20(Diana.pdf).

There are other clustering algorithms which you may google up, some already mentioned in other answers. I have not used others so i will leave that out.